# Automata and Formal Languages

Tags: automata, automata-theory

Showing that the reverse of a word for a regular language L is also regular

I am confused as to how I am to approach this question, i've been stuck for hours: For a word x, we use x^r to denote its reverse. For a language L, we use L^r to denote {x^r where x is in the set of L}. Show that if L is regular then so is L^r

Answer (score 1):

If `L` is regular, then there exists some regular grammar which generates it. It can be always represented as either a left-regular grammar, or a right-regular grammar. Let's assume that it's left-regular grammar `G_l`(the proof for right-regular grammar is analogous).

This grammar has productions of two types; the terminating-type:

```
A -> a, where A is non-terminal and a is either a terminal or empty string (epsilon)
```

or the chaining type:

```
B -> Ca, where B, C are non-terminals and a is a terminal
```

When we apply reverse to a regular language, we basically also apply it to the tails of productions (since heads are just single non-terminals). It's going to be proved later on. So we get a new grammar `G_r`, with productions:

```
A -> a, where A is non-terminal and a is either a terminal or empty string (epsilon)
B -> aC, where B, C are non-terminals and a is a terminal
```

But hey, it's a right-regular grammar! So the language it accepts is also regular.

There is one thing to do - to show that reversing tails actually does the thing it's supposed to. We're going to prove it very simply:

1. If `L` contains \epsilon, then there is production 'S -> \epsilon' in `G_l`. Since we don't touch productions like that, it's also present in `G_r`.
2. If `L` contains `a`, a word composed of a single terminal, then it's similar to the above
3. If `L` contains `aZ`, where a is a terminal and `Z` is a word from the language constructed from chopping off the first terminals out of words in `L`, then `L^r` contains (because of changes to the chaining productions) `(Z^r)a`. Z is also a regular language, since it can be constructed by dropping the first "level" of left-productions from `G_l`, which leaves us with a regular grammar.

I hope it helped. There's also an arguably easier way of doing that by reversing edges of the relevant finite automata and changing accepting and entry states a bit.